# Customising log4j adapter

Tags: java, log4j

I want to build my own custom log4j (network) adapter to solve my problem [that I posted here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505/deserialize-in-a-different-language)

I have looked at the documentation on the log4j and I cant see where/if the developers go into how to do this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get started?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Write custom appenders for log4j](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2004/jw-1220-toolbox.html)

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that you leverage the existing SyslogAppender?