# Java serialization vs MsgPack vs Bson

Tags: java, spring, serialization, websocket

I am working with websockets, i want the process of sending/recieving data be as fast as possible. I have come across BSON and MsgPack libraries for binary serialization. However, using simple tests:

```
@Message
class MessageTemplate implements Serializable {
    public String msg;
}

public class test {
    static void start(){
        MessageTemplate x = new MessageTemplate();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            x.msg += UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        System.out.println("===============================================================");
        {
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            byte[] bytes = SerializationUtils.serialize(x);
            MessageTemplate x1 = (MessageTemplate) SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            long duration = (endTime - startTime);
            System.out.println("TIME1:" + String.valueOf(duration) + ", SIZE: " + bytes.length);
        }
        System.out.println("===============================================================");
        MessagePack msgpack = new MessagePack();

        {
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            try {
                byte[] b = msgpack.write(x);
                MessageTemplate dst = msgpack.read(b, MessageTemplate.class);
                long endTime = System.nanoTime();
                long duration = (endTime - startTime);
                System.out.println("TIME1:" + String.valueOf(duration) + ", SIZE: " + b.length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
starting===============================================================
TIME1:2560388, SIZE: 36171
===============================================================
TIME1:93729732, SIZE: 36013
```

It seems that serialization is way faster than MsgPack. However searching i have found not any mentioning of java serialization as "serializating library/format".

What are the drawbacks of using it? Why is it or isnt used? The only drawback i see is that mobile app will have ios/android client, so there wont be java on both sides in every case.

Thanks for help and answers.

Comment: you could give a try to protobuf also, we use in our project...

Comment: Only use Java serialization if both sides are Java. See [Deserialize in a different language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29505/5221149).